# Image grid - labels?

Tags: orange

I was wondering if labels could be visualized below images in the image grid tool in Image Analytics?

I know, this feature might be not terribly useful for images in general, hence unlikely to be deployed in Orange. How hard it would be to modify  `image_grid.py` in order to display such image names? Any pointers would be useful.

Comment: This is an enhancement request you should probably raise here: https://github.com/biolab/orange3-imageanalytics/issues